# How to validate request headers in kubernetes

Tags: validation, kubernetes, amazon-eks, request-headers

I have a kubernetes cluster and i have more than 15 microservices running in it, Each REST API send me a custom header lets say "version":"1.2.0", i need to check this version from each REST api and throw a custom error if it doesn't match with the value i have.

Suppose i have a mobile app and i have released a new version of the app and redeployed the microservices to match the new app, i want to throw a custom error to users using the old application to download the new app to continue using the application.

Is there a way to achieve this using ingress-nginx or in the kubernetes level instead of repeating logic in each microservice.

Answer (score 1):

With `Nginx ingress`, you will be able to inject the secret into the request if it's coming outside and forward request to service

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  proxy_set_header My-Custom-Header $http_my_custom_header;
```

since as your all microservices talking internally and routing based on custom header you can use the service mesh `istio`

for example : https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/#route-based-on-user-identity

https://dwdraju.medium.com/simplified-header-based-routing-with-istio-for-http-grpc-traffic-ff9be55f83ca

Comment: This will inject a custom header and the validation we have to do in microservice right?

Comment: yes you have to add validation in micro service side if using the nginx ingress with istio it wont divert traffic to pod if wrong header is there.

Answer (score 0):

[ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) supports [configuration snippets](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) as an annotation.

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($http_version != "1.2.0") {
        return 418;
      }
```

You can configure the ingress to [capture certain error codes](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#custom-http-errors) so the default backend app receives these requests and can build a [custom error response](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/custom-errors/). Be aware that this captures *all* listed error codes. So don't use a status code that the rest of your application might or you might hide a real error response.